# Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is a object and not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ava

I am using node-js and I have this line of code in a file called `utils.js`:

```
const spartial = (func, ...args) => (...rest) => func(...args, ...rest);
```

The file `App.js` contains a class called `App` and this class is using the `spartial` function in `utils.js`.

I have written a unit test using the `ava` library which tests `App.js`, and when I run the test, I get this error:

```
Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is a object and not a function
```

and the following line of code is highlighted in red...

```
 1: const spartial = (func, ...args) => (...rest) => func(...args, ...rest);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here and how I can fix this? I'm not sure if it is the unit test library or not that is causing the issue, but when I run `node utils.js` I don't get any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was entirely because I called the `spartial` function with the paramaters in the wrong order. I don't know how I didn't see this after looking at it for an hour.